# 200 Rewrite blog post links

Tags: php, posts, permalinks

I have an self-hosted website and Wordpress where `mywebpage.com` is my main site and `mywebpage.com/blog` is my Wordpress Blog.

I'm building an new website on AWS Amplify with more modern web languages, and because of that its not as easy to install wordpress in a project folder, and I don't want to lose my blog, so here what I've done so far:

I wrote an 200 Rewrite rule on my new website (Let's call it `newpage.com`) so when I visit `newpage.com/blog` what I actually see is my Wordpress Blog page, I can even visit `newpage.com/blog/interesting-post/`and it would show me the correct post on my blog, all of this without an domain change on the browser.

Here's my problem: The first page on my blog has links to popular posts, categories and etc. If i visit my blog trough my new domain and click on one of the posts there I'm redirected to `mywebpage.com/popular-post`, because the links are not following the 200 Rewrite Rule.

Is there a way to change posts URL to follow the 200 Rewrite rule ?